# String values are passed in as reference to a Python lambda for some reason

Tags: python, python-3.x, lambda, reference, scoping

for some reason, strings appear to be passed in as a reference into a Python lambda. For this reason, only the last values of `type` and `definition` are being used in the lambda functions. The output should be:

```
>>> value (a,b) stuff
>>> time Some stuff
>>> did do otherStuff
```

but instead, I'm getting this as output:

```
>>> did do otherStuff
>>> did do otherStuff
>>> did do otherStuff
```

Any help with understating what is going on would be much much appreciated.

```
# A definition is the text following space after the type name.

# Get a value from the user.
# A value is a int from a to b inclusive.
# Signature in config: value (a,b) name
# str -> int
def get_value(definition):
    print("value " + definition)

# Get a time from the user.
# A time is a float.
# Signature in config: time name
# str -> float
def get_time(definition):
    print("time " + definition)

# Gets a did? from the user.
# A did_do is a bool.
# Signature in config: did_do name
# str -> bool
def get_did_do(definition):
    print("did do " + definition)

# Takes in the data for a config and returns a list of functions to call the meet it's criteria.
# list of str -> list of (none -> str)
def config_to_functions(config):
    type_to_input_functions = get_type_map()

    functions = []

    for line in config:
        line = line.split(" ", 1)

        type = line[0]
        definition = line[1]

        functions.append(lambda: type_to_input_functions[type](definition))
    return functions

# Returns a map of type names to input functions.
# An input function is a fuc(str) -> str.
# none -> map of str to (str -> str)
def get_type_map():
    return {
        "value" : get_value,
        "time" : get_time,
        "did_do" : get_did_do,
        }

# Runs the program.
def main():

    mockConfig = ["value (a,b) stuff", "time Some stuff", "did_do otherStuff"]

    input_functions = config_to_functions(mockConfig)

    for func in input_functions:
        func()

main()
```

Comment: Python uses late-binding, lexically scoped closures. In any case, **everything** in python acts like a reference.

Comment: So, one solution, just create a helper function: `def func_maker(input_func, definition): return lambda: input_func(definition)` then in your `config_to_functions`, just do: `functions.append(func_maker( type_to_input_functions[type], definition))`